# PyQt5 + QML: Empty window with "Unable to assign [undefined] to QString"

Tags: qml, pyqt5

I'm trying PyQt5 + QML, as following:

`test.py`:

```python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import sys, os, math

from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.Qt import *
from PyQt5.QtQuick import * 

class Hello(QObject):
    def get_greeting(self):
        return QString('Hello World!')


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
hello = Hello()
view = QQuickView()

context = view.rootContext()
context.setContextProperty('hello',  hello)
view.setSource(QUrl(__file__.replace('.py', '.qml')))

view.show()
app.exec_()
```

`test.qml`:

```qml
import QtQuick 2.0              

Rectangle {
    color: "red"
    width: 350
    height: 350
    Text {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        font.pointSize: 32
        color: "white"
        text: hello.get_greeting
    }
}
```

It indeed popups a red window, but without any text and console give me a message:

```
"Qt Warning - invalid keysym:dead_actute" 
file:///....../test.qml:11:15: Unable to assign [undefined] to QString
```

Comment: what happens if you do `return "Hello World!"`

Comment: Get the same warning message after removing `QString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution: add a `@pyqtProperty(str)` decorator before `def get_greeting(self):`.